# Get last three digits of an integer

Tags: python, integer, int, digit

I wish to change an integer such as 23457689 to 689, 12457245 to 245 etc.

I do not require the numbers to be rounded and do not wish to have to convert to String.

Any ideas how this can be done in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 24):

Use the `%` operation:

```
>>> x = 23457689
>>> x % 1000
689
```

`%` is the `mod` (i.e. [`modulo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) operation.

Answer (score 11):

To handle both positive and negative integers correctly:

```
>>> x = -23457689
>>> print abs(x) % 1000
689
```

As a function where you can select the number of leading digits to keep:

```
import math
def extract_digits(integer, digits=3, keep_sign=False):
    sign = 1 if not keep_sign else int(math.copysign(1, integer))
    return abs(integer) % (10**digits) * sign
```

The constraint to avoid converting to `str` is too pedantic. Converting to `str` would be a good way to do this if the format of the number might change or if the format of the trailing digits that need to be kept will change.

```
>>> int(str(x)[-3:])
              ^^^^^ Easier to modify this than shoe-horning the mod function.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was simply required to extract the last digits and plot, the values would never change. I could use this as well

Comment: "the values would never change..." said every programmer ever.

Comment: I like this answer because it brings up the issue of possibly negative input, and because it gives the string-based alternative.  However, I don't like that it makes an assumption about how negative input should be handled (what if they want to keep the sign, for example?), and I disagree that the string slicing is any "easier to modify" than the mod function.